# Visualize when Jenkins jobs start and finish

Tags: jenkins

I have 100s of Jenkins jobs, each starting and ending at various times. Is there a plugin that can visualize when all these jobs start and finish on a time series so I can know when my instance is utilized?

Answer (score 1):

You can check dashboard view [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View). If you really want to monitor the jobs and usage of executors, may be you should look at [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) which is a monitoring system with time series
database. Jenkins has Prometheus [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Prometheus+Plugin) which will help to export metrics to Prometheus which you can use to get more insights